# Display WooCommerce products randomly by default on shop page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, sql-order-by

I am trying to display products randomly on my shop page with this code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'set_sort_order');
function set_sort_order($args) {
    $args['orderby'] = 'rand';
    return ($args);    
}
```

But this code makes random product category page, but I need to just store page - front page. Not on product category page. How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following instead to sort products randomly on shop archive pages only:

```
// Set default orderby query to "rand" option for shop archive pages
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'shop_default_orderby_rand');
function shop_default_orderby_rand($args) {
    if( is_shop() && ( ! isset($_GET['orderby']) || 'menu_order' === $_GET['orderby'] ) ) {
        $args['orderby'] = 'rand';
        return ($args);
    }
}
```

Or you can also use this one too:

```
// Set default orderby query to "rand" for shop archive pages
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'shop_default_orderby_rand' );
function shop_default_orderby_rand( $query ) {
    if ( is_shop() && ( ! isset($_GET['orderby']) || 'menu_order' === $_GET['orderby'] ) ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );
    }
}
```

Insert the code in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me, but I found it a better idea to use the plugin, "code snippets" to allow you to put the code in, rather than make changes to the core files. Cheers again.

Comment: This code don't work on archive/category pages, only on shop, any solution?